# Calling function on Phoenix app start

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

What is the simplest way to call the function loading some data from the database on Phoenix app start? So I need my function to have Ecto.Query goodness at it's disposal and been called **before** the Phoenix started serving any requests.

Comment: What about writing a `plug` that checks a specific GenServer has loaded the data? If the data is loaded, continue the `plug` chain, if not, return a 503. That's the simplest implementation I can think of. If you're okay with serving requests with a bad status code, I can write a more detailed answer

Comment: Ideally this function should be called only once after the Phoenix app is started/restarted. And plug will be called on any request. It will be only one check if the info loaded though... More detailed answer will be good.

Answer (score 4):

You can start a worker at startup time between your `Repo` and `Endpoint` supervisors in `my_app/application.ex`:

```
# Define workers and child supervisors to be supervised
children = [
  # Start the Ecto repository
  supervisor(MyApp.Repo, []),

  # The new worker
  worker(MyApp.DoSomething, [], restart: :temporary),

  # Start the endpoint when the application starts
  supervisor(MyAppWeb.Endpoint, []),
  # Start your own worker by calling: MyApp.Worker.start_link(arg1, arg2, arg3)
  # worker(MyApp.Worker, [arg1, arg2, arg3]),
]
```

And create a file `my_app/do_something.ex`:

```
defmodule MyApp.DoSomething do
  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{})
  end

  @impl true
  def init(state) do
    user = MyApp.Accounts.get_user!(1)
    IO.inspect user

    Process.sleep(10_000)
    IO.inspect "Done sleeping"

    # Process will send :timeout to self after 1 second
    {:ok, state, 1_000}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_info(:timeout, state) do
    # Stop this process, because it's temporary it will not be restarted
    IO.inspect "Terminating DoSomething"
    {:stop, :normal, state}
  end
end
```

At startup time, you should see some info printed about the user and after a 10 second delay: `Running MyAppWeb.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://0.0.0.0:4000`.

I'm not 100% sure if this is the best and safest way to do this (perhaps a GenServer is not needed at all?), but it works. The repo is available in the worker and the endpoint does not start until `init` has returned.

Edit: I've updated the code to (hopefully) correctly shutdown the process when it's done.

Comment: That's actually a neat way, didn't know they initialize synchronously. You should prefer this one over a plug based implementation if you don't need http Status codes.

Comment: Thanks for this! Worked a treat.

Answer (score 4):

[This nice post](http://elixir.goodcode.in/2017/07/03/how-to-run-a-chunk-of-code-when-your-elixir-phoenix-app-starts/) also summarized a third way, which is to use the `Task` module. It saves the trouble of having to write a complete Genserver:

```
defmodule Danny.Application do
  use Application
  # ...
  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      supervisor(Danny.Repo, []),
      # ...
      worker(Task, [&CacheWarmer.warm/0], restart: :temporary) # this worker starts, does its thing and dies
      # ...
      ]
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Danny.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

---

Define a module:

```
defmodule CacheWarmer do
  import Logger, only: [debug: 1]
  def warm do
    # warming the caches
    debug "warming the cache"
    # ...
    debug "finished warming the cache, shutting down"
  end
end
```

Note that the only additional line in `your_app.ex` is: `worker(Task, [&CacheWarmer.warm/0], restart: :temporary)`

Answer (score 3):

I give my own answer to my question in addition to the @zwippie great answer, which is more universal and OTP standart but mine is simpler and can fit in some cases.

To call the function right before the Phoenix endpoint starts serving requests we can call it from the init() callback of the Endpoint module of our application, which is called right after the Ecto.Repo.Supervisor started the Ecto.Repo worker.

So if we have :my_app application, we can open lib/my_app_web/endpoint.ex file, find the callback function init() there and call some function from there.